# Javascript: Unicode symbol can not be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

my js and html code is like this:

```
<script>
function addComment(){
var a=document.getElementById("a");
var input=document.getElementById("myinput");
a.innerHTML="<p \u0025></p>";
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<input id="myinput"  type="text"/>
<button onclick="addComment()">input</button>
<p id="a">a</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the result page looks like this, the \u0025 unicode has been transformed into "%"
[image]

However, if i used the value of the input ( in the html code):

```
<script>
function addComment(){
var a=document.getElementById("a");
var input=document.getElementById("myinput");
a.innerHTML=input.value;
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<input id="myinput"  type="text"/>
<button onclick="addComment()">input</button>
<p id="a">a</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I tried to input the string "

"
the unicode can not be transformed into "%":

[image]
[image]

Comment: And why would a unicode character be valid inside the paragraph tag ?

Comment: Im trying to test the mutation XSS attack, lets say if I input"<p onmouseover="alert('xss attack')">sss<>", the server side may not allow this string to pass to the innerHtml, but if the inside stuff is hidden by unicode like \u0022, the server side may not be able to detect this. I saw this stuff from a paper named "mXSS Attacks: Attacking well-secured Web Application"

Answer (score 0):

You have two different strings equivalent to:

1. `"<p \u0025></p>"`
2. `"<p \\u0025></p>"`

You would have to evaluate the second string as a JavaScript string literal in order to get the same value:

```
a.innerHTML=eval('"'+input.value+'"');
```